# How can I use electronics right below their operating temperatures?

Tags: temperature

Where I live (south of Sweden) is usually just below 0 Celsius night/day entire dark winter. I would like to set up a network in my garage which is wood and doesn't have any heating system.

The electronics I am planning to use (like powerline, switch etc) have operating temperatures between 0-40.

Should I use electronics without worrying about their operating temperature in my garage?

Other option I have been thinking is using the heat generated by electronics to heat up their environment. For example, if I could put all of them into a glass/wood box, the heat generated by them will be enough (I think) to keep the machines in their operating temperature. Is this a good idea? Any other suggestions?

Comment: Freezing temperature for involved chemicals is one hard margin to not go over, but the others are usually only "rapidly increased aging" margins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While components and assemblies generally have some operating "margin" outside of their specified temperature ranges, to some extent they will begin to suffer degraded performance, and this may or may not affect what you are trying to do.

So yes, you do need to pay attention to the operating temperature, either by buying items that are specified to work in your temperature range or by providing a temperature-controlled environment for them. Putting them in an enclosure and relying on self-heating can work, but you'll want to monitor the actual temperature in order to make sure.

If the equipment is on continuously, the temperature should remain fairly stable. If the equipment gets turned off and on, then the start-up at low temperatures could become problematic, and the thermal cycling may introduce other problems with mechanical stress and/or condensation. An auxiliary heater may be required.

In small enclosures, a large PTC thermistor can be used directly as both a heating element and a temperature regulator. For larger enclosures, you may need to have a separate heating element and a circuit to control it.

Answer (score 1):

I think that indeed if you isolate the equipment somewhat then with the heat that is generated by the electronics that should keep the temperature high enough. Most problematic are LCD displays (they contain a fluid which could freeze) and batteries (they lose power) but in a powerline adapter and a switch, I do not expect these to be present. Moisture is always bad for electronics so keeping them dry will help.

That the operating range is 0 up to something doesn't mean the equipment will not work at -10. It might but it is not guaranteed since this is exceptional and more expensive to test.

So I would not worry too much about this, keep the equipment in a plastic box or something and all should be well.

Comment: Oh indeed, I though Sweden, must get cold ;-)